# TikZ Curved Half Arrow Looks Weird

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=1pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [ultra thick, domain=0:90, {Latex[left]}-] plot ({50pt*cos(\x)}, {50pt*sin(\x)});
    \draw [ultra thick, {Latex[left]}-] (0, -5pt) -- (50pt, -5pt);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the obtained arrows are shown as

[image: Result]

where the curved arrowhead is not displayed properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last linesegment in the plot is shorter than the arrow shortening. Here are several options:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[xshift=0pt,  ultra thick, {Latex[red, left]}-] plot[domain=0:90] ({50pt*cos(\x)}, {50pt*sin(\x)});
\draw[xshift=10pt, ultra thick, {Latex[red, left]}-] plot[domain=0:90, samples=10] ({50pt*cos(\x)}, {50pt*sin(\x)});
\draw[xshift=20pt, ultra thick, {Latex[red, left, quick]}-]  (50pt,0) arc[radius=50pt, start angle=0, end angle=90];
\draw[xshift=30pt, ultra thick, {Latex[red, left]}-]         (50pt,0) arc[radius=50pt, start angle=0, end angle=90];
\draw[xshift=40pt, ultra thick, {Latex[red, left, flex=0]}-] (50pt,0) arc[radius=50pt, start angle=0, end angle=90];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Five curved arrows with slightly different endings at arrow heads]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It seems that `arc` is indeed a better solution than `plot` :-)